# Bootstrap 4 input field spacing in Chrome on IOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I've got an issue I cannot seems to figure out. I have a simple form for four text input fields. The spacing looks great on all the browsers except for Chrome on IOS. The spacing between the input fields just seems to be ignored.

I'm using Bootstrap 4. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-5 col-6 pt-2">
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="First name">
  </div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-5 col-6 pt-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="Last name">
</div>                      
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-6 pt-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="E-Mail">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-6 pt-2">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="Zip Code" name="loanzip" id="loanzip" maxlength="5" value="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-5 col-12 search-results pt-2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm rounded font-size-15">Get Approved <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true">    </i></button>
</div>
```

So frustrating when it looks Ok everywhere else.

Enclosed is a screen shot from Chrome on IOS.

Thanks for any help!

Tim

[image: chrome IOS screenshot]

Here it is on mobile Safari...

[image: mobile safari screenshot]

Latest HTML but leaves extra spacing after the button only on IOS Chrome.

```
<form name="carloan" id="carloan" action="car-loan-application/" method="post">
<div class="row ml-2 mr-2">
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 mb-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 mb-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 mb-2">
  <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="E-Mail">
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 mb-2">
  <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-color-light-gray2" placeholder="Zip Code">
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-xl-4 mb-2 search-results">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm rounded font-size-15">Get Approved <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I can see your using `col-md-3` which is for tablets, you are to use "col-xs (portrait device) or col-sm (landscape device)" depending on the width on IOS device. Or you can just use media queries or bootstrap 4 `form-group` class for your div (for a proper view). E.g.

`<div class="form-group"> input or form button... </div>`

Comment: If you look at the two screenshots, it's bunched together on Chrome IOS and looks fine on Safari IOS.  I'm using the different col-* to make it look good and different width screens. I've cut and pasted code right from the bootstrap website for a test and Chrome on IOS is just plain weird.

Comment: I think you need some sort of space to sperate your input from one another. Try adding `<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>` at the middle of the div containing your inputs.

Comment: Just for completeness sake: there are no "col-xs-" classes in bootstrap anymore. Those classes got kinda removed / renamed to "col-". See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options for more information.

Comment: Fabian, yes, that's true. Coming from v3 to v4, it can get confusing. I'm not using col-xs-*. I wish I knew why Chrome on IOS doesn't play by the rules.